# Extension of linear operator into $l^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

Stuck on this homework question, would appreciate any help thanks.

Suppose $E$ is a normed space and $E_0$ is a subspace of $E$, all over a field $\mathbb{K}$. Let $T_0 : E_0 \rightarrow l^\infty $ be a bounded linear operator, where as usual $l^\infty$ is the banach space of all bounded sequences in $\mathbb{K}$ with norm   $||(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} } || = sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_n | $. Then use the Hahn–Banach theorem  to show that there is an extension of $T_0$ to $E$, call it $T$, where $|| T ||  = || T_0 || $.

I think this would be really easy if instead of $l^\infty$ it was just $\mathbb{K} $ ( precisely the statement of the hahn-banach theorem) but not sure how this still works when we change to a different normed space.

Comment: $E_0$ is a subspace of $E$ and $T_0 : E_0 \rightarrow l^\infty $ is just a bounded linear operator from $E_0$ into $l^\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T_nx$ be the $n-$th coordinate of $Tx$. There exists an extension $S_n$ of $T_n$ to $E$ with $\|T_n\|=\|S_n\|$. Let $Sx=(S_1x,S_2x,...)$. It is fairly easy to check that $S$ an extension with $\|S\|=\|T\|$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I actually made an error in the original post so your answer was based off of that error, apologies

Comment: My answer is correct. I have changed notations slightly: my $T$ is your $T_0$ and my $S$ is your $T$. That should not cause any confusion. @turnip_man

Comment: I'm a bit confused, just wondering if you could clear up the following; $Tx$ is a bounded sequence in $l^\infty$, so when you take the $n^{th}$ coordinate, are you mapping from $l^\infty$ into $\mathbb{K}$? In that case, when using Hahn-Banach is the domain starting from $T(E_0)$ and being extended to $T(E)$?

Comment: @turnip_man You are extending the $n-th$ coordinate from $E_0$ to $E$. Do this for each $n$ and put the extended maps from $E$ into $F$ together to get a new map from $E$ into $\ell^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, just one last point, how do know that $Sx$ is a bounded sequence?

Comment: It follows from the fact that $\|S_n\|=\|T_n\|$ and $(T_nx)$ is bounded. @turnip_man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134175/discussion-between-turnip-man-and-kavi-rama-murthy).